# qmake: could not find a Qt installation of ''

Tags: qt, ubuntu, qmake

I have a software in ubuntu that requires me to run qmake  to generate the Makefile.

However, running qmake gives back this error,

```
qmake: could not find a Qt installation of ''
```

I have installed what I thought to be the required packages using,

```
sudo apt-get install qt4-qmake
sudo apt-get install qt5-qmake
```

But the error didn't go away.

Any help on this would be gladly appreciated!

Comment: Try running `sudo apt-get install qtcreator`. It installs the full Qt SDK + an IDE. It should add everything you need.

Comment: Hi @sashoalm, thanks a lot, seems I had other packages missing. Now its working :D

Comment: This is not a good solution as it will install many potentially unneeded packages.

Answer (score 208, accepted):

`sudo apt-get install qt5-default` works for me.

```
$ aptitude show qt5-default
```

tells that

> This package sets Qt 5 to be the default Qt version to be used when using
> development binaries like qmake. It provides a default configuration for
> qtchooser, but does not prevent alternative Qt installations from being used.

Comment: Can you please decribe your solution more?

Comment: the accepted answer is not an answer at all. This one should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Following sets up the complete qt5 development installation for me:

apt-get install qt5base-dev qtdeclarative5-dev qt5-qmake qt5-default qttools5-dev-tools 

And then check using:  
qtchooser -print-env

Comment: `E: Package 'qt5-default' has no installation candidate` ubuntu 22.04

Comment: @JannisIoannou Try to install 'qt5-qmake-bin' instead

Comment: Use this `apt-get install qtbase5-dev qtchooser qt5-qmake qtbase5-dev-tools`  https://askubuntu.com/a/1335187/1005427

Comment: So which version of Qt, and where installation folder of Qt if we used qt5-default.

Answer (score 30):

You could check path to qmake using `which qmake`.

Consider install `qt4-default` or `qt5-default` depends what version of qt you want use.

You could also use [qtchooser](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/man1/qtchooser.1.html)  -  a  wrapper  used  to select between Qt development binary versions.

Comment: Hi @Warthel4578, thanks, your answer helped me indirectly, since I installed qt4-qmake, I should have invoked 'qt4-qmake' instead of 'qmake' (I found both of them in the directory path). Now its working :)

Comment: Thanks Warthel  this helped me discover why my qmake wasn't working. qmake on Ubuntu 14.04 was symlinked to qtchooser

Comment: I got to this SO answer, then found, based on the next error (`no qtwebkit installation found`) that I also had to run `apt-get install qt5-default libqt5webkit5-dev gstreamer1.0-plugins-base gstreamer1.0-tools gstreamer1.0-x` as described on [the Thoughtbot Github wiki page](https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/wiki/Installing-Qt-and-compiling-capybara-webkit#debian--ubuntu)

Answer (score 20):

As Debian Qt's maintainer please allow me to suggest you to *not* use qtx-default. Please read qtchooser's man page, the solution is described there. If you are interested in packaging an app you can also take a look at [this blog post I made explaining how to do it](http://perezmeyer.blogspot.com.ar/2013/08/qt-in-debian-using-qt4-andor-qt5-in.html)

```
# method 1
QT_SELECT=qt5 qmake

# method 2:
export QT_SELECT=qt5
qmake
... more qt commands here

# method 3:
make -qt5
```

To use Qt 4, just replace the `qt5` with `qt4`

**Update 20210202:** starting from Debian 11 (bullseye) the packages qtx-default do not longer exist. Same goes for Ubuntu, but I don't know in which specific version. If you know of a package that still has the dependency (mostly non-Debian official packages) please file a bug. Same goes for Wiki pages, etc.

Comment: Can you explain why we shouldn't use qtx-default, please? The qtchooser manpage helps me understand what is going on, but I don't see why having a package supply a default is a problem.

Comment: It would be nice if qmake-qtX was bundled under the relevant qt version. Pulling in these pieces is bit cumbersome.

Comment: @RobieBasak sure thing: let's say you install qt5-default. Then you run a qt4 application which calls qdbus. You get qt5's qdbus, which should work but it's not warranted to do it.

Comment: Surely that's a bug in how the qt4 application calls qdbus or in the environment the qt4 application was run in, rather than my choice to want qt5 by default from my CLI?

Comment: First thing: maybe qdbus was a bad example. Let's say upstream decided to not rename Qt's underlying tools with the 4 to 5 change. So it is not possible to know beforehand which version the app will run except you have qtchooser in the middle. But qtchooser, even if it's a nice attempt, does fall short in a number of places, at least in the distro world. Ideally each app should be either be recalled after the major version *or* compatibility should be retained.

Answer (score 18):

For others in my situation, the solution was:

```
qmake -qt=qt5
```

This was on Ubuntu 14.04 after install qt5-qmake. qmake was a symlink to qtchooser which takes the -qt argument.

Comment: This works also on Linux Mint 21 to start compilation of Qt5 applications

Answer (score 9):

I had this problem building jasmine-headless-webkit Ruby gem. Despite having qt4 installed, `qmake` (a symlink to `qtchooser`) insisted it didn't know about a QT installation. OTOH, it was able to list qt4 when asked directly.

This made everything better:

```
export QT_SELECT=qt4
```

qtchooser then knew to use qmake-qt4, and so on.

Comment: Perfect! I had the same problem when trying to install qBittorrent, and mine was solved with `export QT_QMAKE=/usr/bin`. Never know when those environment variables will come back to bite ya!

Answer (score 4):

Search where is **qmake-qt4**:

```
which qmake-qt4
```

For example qmake-qt4 is in this path:

```
/usr/bin/qmake-qt4
```

Create symbolic link:

```
cd /usr/local/sbin/
ln -s /usr/bin/qmake-qt4 .
mv qmake-qt4 qmake
```

Regards

Answer (score 3):

- Install qt using:

  ```
  sudo apt install qt5-qmake
  ```
- Open `~/.bashrc` file:

  ```
  vim ~/.bashrc
  ```
- Added the path below to the `~/.bashrc` file:

  ```
  export PATH="/opt/Qt/5.15.1/gcc_64/bin/:$PATH"
  ```
- Execute/load a `~/.bashrc` file in your current shell

  ```
  source ~/.bashrc
  ```
- Try now `qmake` by using the version command below:

  ```
  qmake --version
  ```

Answer (score 1):

I have qt4 installed.  I found that using the following path worked for me, despite 'which qmake' returning /usr/bin/qmake, which is just a link to qtchooser anyway.

The following path works for me, on a 64 bit system.  Running from the full path of:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/bin/qmake
```

Comment: Of all the answers this is actually the only one that remotely worked. Except I needed to use `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/qmake`.

Answer (score 0):

A symbolic link to the desired version, defined globally:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/qmake-qt5 /usr/bin/qmake
```

... or per user:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/qmake-qt5 /home/USERNAME/.local/bin/qmake
```

... to see if it works:

```
qmake --version
```

Comment: how about to add a comment, why this answer was down-voted? failing to understand or to apply the solution does not exactly qualify as a valid reason ...while I'm pretty certain it works, because I have it working just like that.

Comment: Throwing the upvote your way because I'm not an apt-get tard, and I actually build from source, and this symlink answer was the closes to getting me on track because I forgot I had aliased my 'qmake'. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For my Qt 5.7, open QtCreator, go to Tools -> Options -> Build & Run -> Qt Versions gave me the location of qmake.

Answer (score 0):

if assistant is run from terminal directly, it will use the default path, usually is the /usr/bin/assistant. I had similar situation, to make it work, all I had to do is to find the actual installation of my qt installation bin path, like xxx/Qt5.13.2/5.13.2/gcc_64/bin/, type xxx/Qt5.13.2/5.13.2/gcc_64/bin/assisstant directly from terminal