# qmake: could not find a Qt installation of '' - Setting up qmake?

Tags: qt, qmake

> qmake: could not find a Qt installation of ''

This thread was not of any help to me. [qmake: could not find a Qt installation of ''](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16607003/qmake-could-not-find-a-qt-installation-of).

How can I get qmake to recognize where the Qt folder is?

Right now it is installed in `/opt/Qt5.1.0`.

Comment: Try to run qmake by full path e.g. `/opt/Qt5.1.0/bin/qmake`.

Comment: I get the same error message.

Comment: I think it's because my Qt installation directory need to be setup in $PATH. Any good tutorials on setting up $PATH environment vars?

Comment: With mentioning /opt in your question, I assume that you're using linux, in which case: http://superuser.com/questions/488173/how-can-i-edit-the-path-on-linux

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16607003/qmake-could-not-find-a-qt-installation-of

Comment: God qmake is a godawful mess. I wish people would stop using it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Have you installed the qt5-default ? You need to do this in addition to running the Qt supplier .run file.

```
sudo apt-get install qt5-default
```

Comment: qt5-default brings 131 other packages with it.
I want to use qmake on a remote server where I don't need any x11 packages at all. How could I avoid all this x11-bull-shit installation but get qmake working well?

Answer (score 4):

This message shown by qtchooser app.
To setup it properly,  you should make conf files in /etc/xdg/qtchooser/

for example:

```
$ ls -1 /etc/xdg/qtchooser/
default.conf
qt-4.8.5.conf
qt-5.1.0.conf
```

each file has two lines: path to bin, path to lib:

```
$ cat /etc/xdg/qtchooser/default.conf 
/opt/Qt/4.8.5/bin
/opt/Qt/4.8.5/lib
```

additional info: man qtchooser

Answer (score 2):

The solution for me on this problem was to specify the QT version, as this message was being generated by /usr/bin/qtchooser

So in my case, it was QT4 I was trying to use, and running:

```
qmake
```

generated the error (could not find a Qt installation of '')

```
qmake -qt=qt4
```

fixed that error though. In my case, it was a Ruby Gem trying to compile with qmake, so I couldn't get it to pass in that extra command line argument, so I instead added this to my profile

```
export QT_SELECT=qt4
```

And now QT4 runs just fine on my Ubuntu system.

Answer (score 1):

For me the symlink to default.conf was missing in /usr/share/qtchooser. It wasn't enough to put it into /etc/xdg/qtchooser.